# How can I apply this style only on the first page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

**CODE JS:**

```
$('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
$('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);
$(window).on('resize',function(){

    $('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
    $('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);

});
```

These functions should be applied only on the first page.
Can I access different div style to apply only on the first page?

I tried to put this code, but unfortunately does not work ... apply on all pages.

**CODE CSS:**

```
article>.entry-content{height:auto !important;}
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
 if ( window.currentPage == "homepage" ) {

    $('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
    $('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);
    $(window).on('resize',function(){

    $('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
    $('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);

    });
 }
```

Code work in document.ready code only go in ... if you put in resize function not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad way,

You can check specific DOM element length which only added on homepage

```
// #onlyhomepage Only exist DOM on homepage
if ( $("#onlyhomepage").length ) {

    $('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
    $('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);
    $(window).on('resize',function(){

        $('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
        $('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);

    });

}
```

Good way,

Simply add a global JavaScript variable on your homepage

HTML ( Homepage HTML )

```
<script>
    window.currentpage = "homepage";
</script>
```

JavaScript ( External Js File )

```
if ( window.currentPage == "homepage" ) {

    $('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
    $('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);
    $(window).on('resize',function(){

        $('.entry-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
        $('.entry-content').css('height', $('.entry-content').outerHeight() - 50);

    });

}
```

Comment: `window.currentpage = "homepage"; ` this code can i add in my file JS?for example custom.js?

Comment: This code must be in homepage html code. If you can't access the html code, you can proceed the "bad way".

Comment: I use WordPress and added code in header.php in section head

Comment: Yes. Before external javascript call. <script>window.currentpage = "homepage";</script><script src="custom.js></script>

Comment: is something strange to me ... you can check than site please watch the show ... I edited my new code http://i62.tinypic.com/24wworc.png

Comment: Maybe something else causes this. Please check your css manipulation codes where only applied on homepage.